# Django psycopg2.ProgrammingError relation does not exist using custom model Manager

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm unable make any migrations from scratch with my current codebase.

Running `./manage.py makemigrations reports` gives the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "reports_frozenschedule" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._file", "reports_frozenschedule"."abandoned" FROM "reports_f...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 342, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/piesup2/urls.py", line 9, in <module>
    from reports.api import viewsets
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/reports/api/viewsets.py", line 77, in <module>
    class ActiveServerViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/reports/api/viewsets.py", line 78, in ActiveServerViewSet
    queryset = Server.active.all()
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 160, in all
    return self.get_queryset()
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/reports/models.py", line 550, in get_queryset
    fqdn__in=active_server_fqdns()
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/reports/models.py", line 541, in active_server_fqdns
    f.deserialize.servers for f in FrozenSchedule.objects.active()
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/jwe/Documents/piesup2/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "reports_frozenschedule" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._file", "reports_frozenschedule"."abandoned" FROM "reports_f...
```

Following the stack trace, the breaking starts when Djagno scans my urls.py file, which looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework import routers

from reports.api import viewsets

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'active-servers', viewsets.ActiveServerViewSet)
...

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('reports.urls')),
]
```

It reaches `from reports.api import viewsets` where it imports the following:

`viewsets.py`

```
from reports.models import Server

...

class ActiveServerViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Server.active.all()
    ...
```

It makes it to `Server.active.all()` which relies on a custom Model Manager shown here:

`models.py`

```
class ActiveServerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ActiveServerManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            fqdn__in=active_server_fqdns()
        )


class Server(models.Model):
    fqdn = models.CharField(....)
    ....
    objects = models.Manager()
    active = ActiveServerManager()
```

My server model manager calls the fucntion `active_server_fqdns()` which looks as follows:

```
def active_server_fqdns():
    # Returns flat set of FQDN's associated with all currently active Schedules
    return {server.fqdn for servers in [
        f.deserialize.servers for f in FrozenSchedule.objects.active()
    ] for server in servers}
```

This function envokes FrozenSchedule.objects.active() inside the set comprehension, which is where everything explodes

The custom queryset `FrozenSchedule.objects.active()` is shown below.

Here Django complains that `the relation "reports_frozenschedule" does not exist`

```
class FrozenScheduleQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def active(self):
        return self.filter(
            Q(start_date__lte=Now()), Q(end_date__gte=Now()) | Q(end_date=None)
        )

class FrozenSchedule(models.Model):
      ....
      objects = FrozenScheduleQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Why would my model managers be causing my database migrations to fail?

It appears there is some kind of race condition occuring from urls.py resulting in the queryset beign evaluated before the table has actually been registered.

## Update with fix

The fix was, as suggested to get rid of the module level query. I've moved it into the get_queryset() method provided by DjangoRestFramework, like:

```
class ActiveServerViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.LinkedServerSerializer
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Server.active.all()
```

Then since it no longer has a queryset attribute I had to add a base_name argument to my viewset

`router.register(r'active-servers', viewsets.ActiveServerViewSet, 'Server')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by module-level code interacting with the database:

```
class ActiveServerViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Server.active.all()
```

This code is run at module-loading time when you run  `makemigrations` and, as you have laid out, leads to a `FrozenSchedule` `QuerySet` being evaluated (`for f in FrozenSchedule.objects.active()`) when the according database table does not exist yet.

You should generally avoid having module-level code (that includes class definitions outside of methods) doing db queries as this code is executed upon module import which is often when you start the server or run a management command.

See [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26273) for example:

> you should never execute queries at module level

Comment: You can fix the problem by overriding the `get_queryset` method instead of `queryset`, and moving the `Server.active.all()` query inside that.